# Having an issue with duplicates after I insert into my suppression table

Tags: sql-server, query, troubleshooting

Hey guys thank you so much in advance for the help.

I do mailings every 3 months.

I know I am missing records where there is a null. I delete those so that's not the issue

I noticed one of my queries is not working and its driving me nuts:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [steve].[dbo].[newfile] 
where addr not in  
(Select addr from steve.dbo.suppression)
```

This gives me address I know I have never mailed to. 'Suppression' table is my list of people i have mailed once.

```sql
SELECT * 
into steve.dbo.stevenew 
FROM [steve].[dbo].[newfile] 
where addr in  
(Select vin from steve.dbo.suppression)
```

This tells me I have mailed to the address before

```sql
select * from [steve].[dbo].[stevenew]
left join [steve].[dbo].[suppression]
on ([suppression].lname <> [stevenew].lname
and [suppression].addr = [stevenew].addr)
where [suppression].addr<>''
```

This tells me its the same house but a new person (lname) living there

```sql
select * 
from [steve].[dbo].[stevenew]
left join [AUTOSTEVEKMASTER].[dbo].[full9282020]
on ([suppression].lname = [stevenew].lname
and [suppression].addr = [stevenew].addr)
where [suppression].addr<>''
```

This tells me which names I have mailed before at this house (Lname and addr match)

Now I insert these names from steve.dbo.stevenew using this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO [steve].[dbo].[suppression] (addr, lname)
SELECT addr, lname
FROM [steve].[dbo].[stevenew]
WHERE [steve].[dbo].[stevenew].addr<> '';
```

The issue I am having is when I run this query again to double check they loaded properly, I still get results saying there are records where there shouldn't be any, since I did the insert into query earlier.

Any help would be amazing, thank you

```sql
select * from [steve].[dbo].[stevenew]
left join [steve].[dbo].[suppression]
on ([suppression].lname <> [stevenew].lname
and [suppression].addr = [stevenew].addr)
where [suppression].addr<>''
```

Comment: Little tough following your situation, it seems you've provided extra information that's not related but also could use some more information too. The best thing you could do is just create a reproducible example on something like [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk) and then link it in your Post.